# C# .Net Covariance - once more for old times sake?

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

So we have this:

```
public interface IWidget
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Widget : IWidget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetProcessor
{
    public static void ProcessWidgets1(IList<IWidget> widgets)
    { }

    public static void ProcessWidgets2<T>(IList<T> widgets) where T : IWidget
    { }
}
```

I get why this wouldn't compile:
`WidgetProcessor.ProcessWidgets1(new List<Widget>());`
The C# rules around covariance wisely say it shouldn't, or you could get up to all sorts of naughtiness, as explained at length elsewhere.

But ProcessWidgets2: what the...?
How is it that this **does** compile and run:
`WidgetProcessor.ProcessWidgets2(new List<Widget>());`

Look forward to having my ignorance removed, but I can't see how ProcessWidgets1 and ProcessWidgets2 are (effectively) any different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ProcessWidgets2<T>` is a generic method.  When you call it with `new List<Widget>()`, the compiler infers that the type `T` is `Widget`, which matches the constraints, and calls it, since `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`.

It's potentially easiest to look at it as if it was broken up into multiple calls:

```
IList<Widget> temp = new List<Widget>();
WidgetProcessor.ProcessWidgets2<Widget>(temp); // Widget is an IWidget, so this matches constraints
```

There is no variance in play here, since `List<T>` directly implements `IList<T>`, and you're calling with a *specific type* that's inferred by the compiler.

Comment: Generic inference!!  Thank you - as soon as the inferred parameter is explicitly included in the call it becomes clear.

Answer (score 0):

With the first example you could execute the code:

```
widgets.Add(new SomeOtherWidget());
```

If `widgets` were actually allowed to be a `List<Widget>` then you would have put a `SomeOtherWidget` into a list of `Widget` objects.  That would be bad, as when you got an object out it might not be a `Widget` at all.

With the second example, `widgets.Add(new SomeOtherWidget());` won't compile.  `SomeOtherWidget` won't be of type `T`.  You will only ever be allowed to call `Add` on the list with an object of type `T`, rather than any old `IWidget` object, so it's able to maintain type safety.